# Ajuda aqui com um exercicio de Ruby

Tags: ruby

Por que mesmo eu digitando 0 ou 2 ele não sai do segundo while

```
while opt==2
print "Digite o valor a ser depositado: "
deposito = gets.chomp.to_f
saldo = saldo + deposito
print "Pressione 0 para voltar ao menu anterior ou 2 para novo deposito: "
opt = gets.chomp.to_i
    while opt!=0 or opt!=2
       print "Opção inválida, pressione 0 para voltar ao menu anterior ou 2 
       para novo deposito: "
       opt = gets.chomp.to_i   
     end
```

end

Comment: Se você digita 2, será diferente de zero e ficará no loop; se você digita 0, será diferente de dois e ficará no loop. A única possibilidade que satisfaria a sua condição é se o número for igual a 0 e igual a 2 ao mesmo tempo, o que é impossível no domínio dos números inteiros. Assim, reveja a sua condição e faça testes de mesa para validá-la.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que você não esteja conseguindo sair do 2º while pela dupla condição: `while opt!=0 or opt!=2`

Veja um problema semelhante ao seu, em inglês: [Multiple conditions in a “While” loop Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16765365/multiple-conditions-in-a-while-loop-ruby)

Um jeito simples de resolver é utilizando a [estrutura de decisão if](https://www.devmedia.com.br/estruturas-de-decisao-e-repeticao-no-ruby/33679), dentro da estrutura de repetição while:

```
while true
   print "Opção inválida, pressione 0 para voltar ao menu anterior ou 2 
   para novo deposito: "
   opt = gets.chomp.to_i   
   if opt!=0 or opt!=2
    break
    end
end
```

Entretanto, recomendo a leitura da pergunta, em inglês, para melhorar seu código.